# Why is subprocess looping over the same set of files over and over

Tags: shell, python-3.x, subprocess

So I want to call on a shell script from Python using

```
from subprocess import call
```

on a group of files with the same extension located in different directories.  Here's what I have so far:

```
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith(".avg"):
                    os.chdir(os.path.join(path))
                    call("shell_script *avg", shell=True)
                    print("creating new file for... " + name)
```

But it just keeps looping over the same set of files over and over and eventually after like 5 iterations it'll move on to the next set of files and do the same thing.  I only found this out because I'm looking at the kernel and see it performing the same shell script on the same files over and over.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`call("shell_script *avg", shell=True)` calls `shell_script` on each file ending in `avg`. The loop does this once for each file ending in `avg`.

Answer (score 1):

You keep changing the current working directory with `os.chdir(os.path.join(path))`. If you are using a relative path in `dir_path` then you keep changing the base of the walk. Instead, skip changing the directory in the main program and set it in the subprocess call instead. Also, you need to pass the actual filename instead of the glob.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".avg"):
            call("shell_script {}".format(name), shell=True, cwd=path)
            print("creating new file for... " + name)
```

Comment: ohhh i thought it would change the directory to make sure the new file gets created in the same directory it's found in.  If I wanted to add arguements I'd just put each argument in quotes and its value like so?

    call("shell_script.sh", "arg1", "value_for_arg1", shell=True, cwd=path)

or does calling the shell=True part mean that the shell is seaprating the arguments behind the scences and the script and arguments should be one long string like so:

    call("shell_script.sh arg1 value_for_arg1", shell=True, cwd=path)